# Python Login System that supports multiple logins

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter, login-system

This is a project that I wanted to work on. I want a program that people can enter their login details and their username and password information will be sent to another program that will check to see if the login details are right and then will tell the other program whether they can login or not.

The problem is I have no idea how I will make the programs send data to each other. If anyone could help me, maybe introduce me to some new modules that could help me, I would be very happy.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

The program that you want to send the data to confirm if it'll work has to be able to allow such method of confirmation, else, it wouldn't work. If it does, it may be that you would have to supply such to the program from the command line.

You could try out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/EasyProcess

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a sort of client-server setup here, you could look into using [sockets](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) in order to facilitate the communications between the client and server software. However, I would advise that you keep in mind that sending information such as passwords over the net will probably require that they be secured as well.

I'm sorry if I'm a little unhelpful with your project, but the vague nature of your description was such that I can only really point you towards the modules you may want to look into for accomplishing the key aspect of your task.